# How to insert multiple rows in one execute? SQFLite Flutter

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am new using sqflite, I come from android studio where by for's I build a query with more than 1 row, which was this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO clientes (codigo, empresa, nombre, e_mail) VALUES (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?)
```

then again using for, I inserted the values with the bind.

My problem is that now I'm trying to do the same function but in Flutter .. and I can't find the way because i didnt find any function called "binds" like in android studio .. I know that with Flutter it is easier to handle the Maps with SQFLite but I don't know the way ... at the moment I have this dynamically armed query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO clientes (codigo, empresa, nombre, e_mail) VALUES (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?)
```

How do I now pass the values dynamically in flutter?
because this executes it and inserts it, but of course in the DB what you see is `"NULL NULL NULL NULL"` clearly because I am not passing the values to the arguments ... could you help me or guide me on how to do it?

I was thinking that if, I could pass those values dynamically from a map? How should I do some practical example could you give me?
or with a list? for ex
[{2, asd, asd, asd@mail.com}, {3, asd, asd, asd@mail.com}]
and dynamically insert each 1 of those 2 items as arguments ... could you give me a practical example if this is possible?

thanks since now